# How to filter 100s of records using jquery sliders with out going to server every time?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json, jsp

I have a requirement like i have to show 1000's of records in JSP.And i have to filter the records by using the Jquery Slider.Now i am sending request to server for each move.Is there any easy way to filter the records With out sending the request to server.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this without a round trip to the server, you need to load all the data you need in the client. This of course will take a lot of time initially and could be a hog for the client. I guess that for a couple thousand of records it will be ok. Load them to the client using ajax, so that the browser stays responsive. Load all the data even if you initially need to show a fraction of them. Depending on the slider selection show more or less.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the record properties into the DOM. For instance, you can do the following:

```
//assuming you get your results via ajax/JSON
search_filter = new Array();
$.ajax({
   success: function(json) {
      for (var key in json) {
         search_filter.push(json[key]) //this loop might not be necessary depending on how json looks like
      }
   }
});

//We define jRecords globally for performance gains, however, updates to the table are not registered
var jRecords = $('table#relevant_table>tr');
$('input#search').bind('change', function() {
   var jExceptions = $;
   var this_value = $(this).val();
   var size = jRecords.size();
   for (var i=0; i<size; i++) {
      if (search_filter[i].relevant_value > this_value) {
         jExceptions.add(jRecords.eq(i));
      };
   }

   jRecords.not(jExceptions).hide();
   jExceptions.show();
})
```

This showcases how you *could* use the DOM for filter storage and use that to filter the records via js. I tried to avoid lots of selectors and single actions to gain performance (since you are working with thousands of rows, it might be slow) and instead opted for searching the rows together and update them in one go. However, this example might still not be optimized for your specific task. I also have not tested if the example actually works, but I'm pretty confident it will (expect a few syntax errors though).